# Count number of occurrences for unique value in column by grouping & bring in other columns in result WITHOUT grouping

Tags: sql

I am querying SQL database to identify how many time a CustID appeared in the booking cancellation table with cancellation date range:

```
SELECT CustID
      ,COUNT(*) as Occurance

FROM [Test].[dbo].[vwBookingCancelletion]

WHERE [Cancellation Date] between '2018-12-01' and '2019-12-31'

GROUP BY CustID

ORDER BY occurance desc
```

Output i want to achieve is as below:

[image]

My current query does give me correct out put but when I try to add additional columns in the *select* statement I also have to add it in the *Group by* which brings incorrect output.

I have been trying sub query(learning while typing this) without any success and also few other solutions on SE.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are the additional columns that you want to bring? Sample data and expected results, as tabular text, would make your question easier to understand.

Comment: @GMB, I have added what expect out put i am trying to achieve, additional columns such as CustName, CancellationDate, Vanue etc.are require but without adding them into the Group By

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
select a.*, Occurance
FROM [Test] a inner join
(
       SELECT CustID
      ,COUNT(*) as Occurance
       FROM [Test].[dbo].[vwBookingCancelletion]
       WHERE [Cancellation Date] between '2018-12-01' and '2019-12-31'
       GROUP BY CustID
)b on a.CustID = b.CustID
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i can understand the sub query but somehow its  throwing error  "Incorrect syntax near '=' ", which i believe its not recognizing tables.. could you suggest whats the issue?

Comment: @victor: the last line of the query, `)b inner join a.CustID = b.CustID` should be `) b on a.CustID = b.CustID`.

Comment: Oups, Thanks GMB

Comment: also would adding b.Occurance (since i want occurances from table b) in the first select statement would change anything? (I tried and getting same number of rows)

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs, solved my issue and I am back on the track :)